# Android: Newer Version installing as a Separate App

Tags: android, eclipse, gradle, manifest

I converted the project from eclipse to android studio. I am trying to update the app on Google Playstore using a newer version created in Android Studio.  Instead of updating, the app is installed as a new App.  Package name of Eclipse based project is same as Application Id of Android Studio Project. Playstore is accepting the apk but when user Updates the App, A newer version version of App is installed as a seperate app.
 Older Version code:13 
Newer Version code:14

Comment: May be you have 2 activities in the Manifest with the category <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

Comment: nope, only one activity has a launcher intent.

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti any other guess?

Comment: what is the process that you converted your project ?? 
I recommend to read this [link] [http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/migrate.html] before migrating from Eclipse to Android studio. It will resolve major problems.

Comment: Are the app IDs when they're in the Play Store still the same?

Comment: your keystore might not be same for older and newer ones?

Comment: My guess is that you changed the package name of your application.  Can you post your manifest before and after and also gradle file so someone can check on this?

Comment: Solved the problem. package names were different.. i noticed it wrong..